# Chrome Extension -- Pass an array from popup.js into injected javascript file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

### So close, yet so far...

---

I'm writing a chrome extension, in which a user adds/removes items in a list. This `<ul>` is then stripped of it's `<li>` elements, and these are joined and then thrown into a localStorage item as a delineated list. In a `function` this list is processed and an array is created.

I need to pass this array from a `<script>` running in **popup.js** to a content script, **inject.js**, which is injected into a [https://twitter.com/*/*](https://twitter.com/) page. As an aside, I have made all necessary manifest entries. I've read the chrome extension documentation, and many stack-overflow answers, yet I have not yet gotten a clear understanding of what I need to do in order to wrap the "array passing" logic into a function which simply makes the array available to **inject.js**.

Let's say that the array is created in popup.js something like this:

```
// inside popup.js
var list;

function getList() {
    lists["list"] = localStorage["myAwesomeList"].split("**%**");
    return lists;
}

function sendListToInjectJs() {
    list = getList();

    // some amzing code that makes my script available to inject.js  
}
```

As shown above, I'd like a function that, when called, sends the created array to **inject.js** where it is held in a variable for processing:

```
// in inject.js
var list = listPassedFromPopupJs;

// sweet list processing here
```

I really feel like this should be easier than I've found. It seems like i should be able to say to **inject.js**, "hey, here's an updated version of that array. Do something with it."

**Thank you in advance for any insight in how to accomplish this!!! My extension will be complete once this bridge is gapped.**

Comment: are you injecting your code directly into the page (by manually creating a script tag and `appendChild`-ing to `document.body` or are you embedding via a `content-script`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [sendMessage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#event-onMessage)

To send array from your **popup.js**:

```
chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, [1,2,3] + "");
```

To receive array in the **inject.js**:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
  console.log(message.split(","));
});
```

Comment: Awesome!!! works great! with your popup.js code, i just had to make sure that tabs was defined by querying for them with chrome.tabs.query()

Comment: i've tried this, but my `runtime` object doesn't have an `onMessage` property available. any idea why this might be?